# R error "object 'required_pkgs' not found whilst loading namespace 'timetk'"

Tags: r

I am using R 4.0.3 with RStudio 1.2.5033 on macOS 11.1.

I have successfully installed the package using `install.packages("timetk")`.
When trying to load the package with `library(timetk)`, I get the following error:

*Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘timetk’:
object 'required_pkgs' not found whilst loading namespace 'timetk'*

I do not know how to solve this. Can anyone please offer help or advice?

Thank you,
C

Comment: I had the same problem, find a possible solution here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833156/load-namespace-issue-in-r/65851937#65851937).

Comment: The correct answer is to update recipes R package. This problem goes away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matt Dancho found the problem for me: update 'recipes'

Comment: Can confirm this solution.  Installing the package `recipes` solved this issue. It was not clear from the error message. (as on 2021-02-14)

Comment: This should be the correct answer @Chris937

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an error with the package, an is a [known issue](https://github.com/business-science/timetk/issues/70) on GitHub.
You could try to install an earlier version of the package if you have one available, while waiting for the author(s) to publish a fix.

At the time of writing, this error occurs both when installing from CRAN and GitHub.