# Load namespace issue in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run some functions with the tidyquant package, but then I've got this error when I run something like `tidyquant::tq_get("AAPL")` or `tidyquant::tq_get("AAPL")`:

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'timetk', details: call: vector("list", length = ncol(frame_mat))
```

If I run `library(timetk)`, I've got the same error.

What can I do? I already reinstall R, but it doesn't work.

Here is my session.

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252
```

Comment: Rather than reinstalling R, reinstall the ‘tidyquant’ package. If that doesn’t work, please report the bug to the ‘tidyquant’ developers.

Comment: I already did, even reinstall R, but it doesn't work. I did report the bug but still find no solution.

Comment: I actually misread the error message: the error happens in the ‘timetk’ package, not in ‘tidyquant’ — but I can see that you already correctly reported the error there.

Comment: Yeah, both packages are related since tidyquant requires timetk. Everything works fine until yesterday; I don't know what is happening.

Comment: There is currently an error in the `timetk` package, which might cause issues further down the stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829423/r-error-object-required-pkgs-not-found-whilst-loading-namespace-timetk/65830393#65830393

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm working on Windows, a solution that I get is to create/edit the .Rprofile in the documents folder. Into this file, I saved the command `require(timetk)`. I'm also working with parallel processing, so this solves this issue.

If anyone still got this problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem - solved for me by the package maintainer Matt Dancho: update package 'recipes'